# Continuously Deploy ASP.Net Core application using PowerShell script in TeamCity

Tags: powershell, msbuild, asp.net-core, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have a ASP.Net Core .xproj. I want to deploy the website continuously on to a server which is hosting the website using IIS. I have TeamCity installed on my server and able to deploy other .NET applications using MSBuild and PowerShell scripts. But now, I want to deploy .NET Core application either using MSBuild or PowerShell or is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is designated [TeamCity dotnet plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-dotnet-plugin) which gives you all required .NET core commands:

- build,
- pack,
- publish,
- restore,
- test

[image]

For dotnet cli parameter specs look in [MS Docs] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/).

Answer (score 0):

While you use `xproj/project.json` concept, you need to use [.NET Core CLI tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/) like `dotnet build`,  `dotnet publish`.

MSBuild has been supporting starting from .NET Core 1.0 Preview 3 and one of the main requirement is a project migration to `csproj` format. See [Announcing .NET Core Tools MSBuild “alpha”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/).